# Allowed memory size exhausted on select from DB

Tags: php, mariadb

My situation is: I have a customer with 3 departments. All 3 are running the same (php)scripts, but have their own database.

I have a development server, a test server and a production server. On the development server and the test server everything is fine. But on the production server in 2 companies the script runs okay, but on the third I got the error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32
> bytes).

I brought the sript back to a single query:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(land,'-',postcode,' ',plaats) AS woonplaats 
FROM bedrijven 
WHERE verwijderd='' 
AND CONCAT_WS('|', naam,toevoeging,faktuurtav,straat,postcode,plaats,telefoon,telefax,mobiel,emailadres,internet,emcpersoon,kvknummer,btwnummer,banknummer,opmerkingen) LIKE '%'
```

If I run the query in phpmyadmin: I got a normal result. But in the script I got the error.
Any ideas what could be the problem.

Comment: Looks like the system does not allow the amount of memory needed to perform the query in your own PHP code. You might want to compare the PHP.INI files on the production server with the development and test server where it runs fine. (Usually when I get this error my script runs in an infinite loop..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is PHP error, it caused by data size fetched from DB.
Looks as data size on Dev & Test servers less then production.

To resolve the problem you have two options:

- first - increase memory used by PHP
- second - optimise the code to
  decrease data set

Comment: I reduced the dataset and that was the best thing.